# Setting the height of a container to another dynamically in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that sets the height of one container to another. I want the height of the .divider_right to be reset if the height of the .content_height changes when resizing the window.

I know I can do this:

```
jQuery(window).resize(function(){     
    var content_height = jQuery(".content_height").outerHeight();
    jQuery(".divider_right").css('height', content_height);
});
```

But this doesn't set the height until the window is resized, so it doesn't show until the window is resized. I need to set the height of .divider_right then resize it if the window is resized.

Comment: Can you please add the html and css code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix would be calling that while `document.ready()`, then later-on as you `resize` it works as added,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var content_height = jQuery(".content_height").outerHeight();
    jQuery(".divider_right").css('height', content_height);
});
```

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ntc5ty55/1/).

Comment: @Reece Try to set that when codes load as above or please add your remaining code to understand issue.